# After downvote my reputation is not decreasing

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Some days before when I was down voting some question or answer, my reputation used to decrease by 2. But since last two days I am noticing that my reputation is not decreasing even if I down vote something. What is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you downvote an answer, your reputation decreases by **1**. When you downvote a question, your reputation does not decrease.

When a question or answer *of yours* gets downvoted, your reputation decreases by **2**.

Also, downvoting or receiving downvotes on any question or answer which is a community wiki post does not decrease your reputation.

If the question or answer gets deleted, the reputation from casting a downvote *or* from downvotes (and upvotes) received (so long as the post did not qualify to keep reputation) will also be reversed.